# Returning a Dynamic Styled Component

Tags: styled-components

I'm trying to return this element but if I try to style it after importing it, it wont apply the correct styles.

`Heading.js`:

```
export default ({
  element = 'h1',
}) => new styled[element]`
  margin: 0 0 ${shevy[element].marginBottom};
  font-family: Plain, sans-serif;
  font-size: ${shevy[element].fontSize};
  line-height: ${shevy[element].lineHeight};
  text-transform: uppercase;
`()
```

`SomeOtherComponent.js`:

```
const LeadHeading = styled(Heading)`
  margin: 0 0 ${bs(3)};
  font-size: ${h4.fontSize};
  line-height: ${h4.lineHeight};
  color: red;
`

<LeadHeading>Yup</LeadHeading>
```

The color is applied correctly but `font-size`, `line-height`, and `margin` aren't applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something hacky, instead I should've been using `withComponent`: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles.

Ended up doing:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import shevy from 'common/shared/utils/shevy'

const Heading = styled.h1`
  font-family: Plain, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
`
const extend = tag => `
  margin: 0 0 ${() => shevy[tag].marginBottom};
  font-size: ${() => shevy[tag].fontSize};
  line-height: ${() => shevy[tag].lineHeight};
`

Heading.h1 = Heading
Heading.h2 = Heading.withComponent('h2').extend(extend('h2'))
Heading.h3 = Heading.withComponent('h3').extend(extend('h3'))
Heading.h4 = Heading.withComponent('h4').extend(extend('h4'))
Heading.h5 = Heading.withComponent('h5').extend(extend('h5'))
Heading.h6 = Heading.withComponent('h6').extend(extend('h6'))

export default Heading
```